# Spring integration - aggregator from sftp inbound

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

What is the best solution to aggregate one message from sftp inbound message source that contains multiple files?
We have on remote machine 3 files that need to be received. After that we combine content of those files to one json message and send it forward.

```
public IntegrationFlow sftpIntegrationFlowBean() {
    final Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("sftpFile", "sftpFile");
    final Consumer<AggregatorSpec> aggregator = t -> {
        t.sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);
        t.expireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
        t.processor(new CustomMessageAggregator());
    };
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(sftpInboundMessageSource(),
                    e -> e.id("sftpIntegrationFlow").poller(pollerMetadataSftp))
            .enrichHeaders(headers).aggregate(aggregator)
            .handle(customMessageSender).get();
}
```

Poller polls every 15 minutes.
While running this code next thing happens:

1. Retrieve files and process one of them
2. After 15 minutes second file is processed
3. After another 15 minutes third file is processed
4. And finally after more 15 minutes message is sent to destination

How can this all be done in one operation without delays? I did try this with FileReadingMessageSource, but had a same result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase `maxMessagesPerPoll` in the `PollerMetadata`.